# MS Azure AD Connect health service high CPU usage

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, entra-id

We're experiencing a windows server high CPU usage since some few last updates. The process that is causing it is the MS Azure AD Connect. Does anyone knows what is the root cause and how to get it back to normal?

Comment: https://dirteam.com/sander/2018/06/18/knowledgebase-high-cpu-usage-for-azure-ad-connect-health-sync-monitor-with-net-framework-4-7-2-installed/

Comment: thanks for the tip, @joeqwerty. The article says we should remove few windows updates and I really don't like this approach since updates are meant to keep things correct in the system. I'm not saying it's not a solution but I prefer not to uncover things already fixed in the system in favor of a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 1):

After some googling, I found that MS has released a new version of Azure AD Connect that solves this issue. Installing this new version (released Aug 1st, 2018) seems to resolve the problem.

Here is the link to download the most recent version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594

The processes is straight forward and will just upgrade the current version installed in the system. No need to reconfigure anything, besides entering the Azure Global Admin account.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect-health/active-directory-aadconnect-health-version-history has details of versions and fixes